# TypeError: SET_NULL() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'collector', 'field', 'sub_objs', and 'using'

Tags: django, django-models

How do i solve the above error which shows up not during the makemigrations but during migrate in Django.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    #comment_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="No Comment Added")
    comment_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    task=models.ForeignKey(task_check, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True )
    task_records=models.ForeignKey(task_check_Records, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Probably you want to set your FK field to a **`null`**, if so, set **`default=None`** instead of **`default=models.SET_NULL`**

Comment: @ArakkalAbu You got me right, I tried that , still the error prevails. Also if I set default=None  while filling the form it still asks me for a value to be filled for task_records.

Comment: if you need to deal with it, set `blank=True` too

Answer (score 0):

Remove files from app_name/migrations and migrate after makemigrations again.

Comment: Is there anyway you can clarify your answer and/or possibly include command line examples?